# Carry out an ORDER BY CAST when NULL is present

Tags: sql-server

A table I have has a column which contains either numbers or a NULL. It is a (VARCHAR(255),Null) column called details.col_rating

I wish to run a query where I select any record where the value is  greater than 165

The query joins 2 tables.

Table Main has details for races.

•   col_id has the number for each unique race.

•   col_racedesc has the race name

•   col_course is the track that a race was run at

•   col_type has the race type code blank, h,b or c

Table Details has the horses details for each race.

•   col_maind is the col_id from the Main table

•   col_fpos is the finishing position in the race

•   col_rating is a figure awarded to the horse.

I would start the query with something like this.

```
SELECT details.col_mainid, 
       details.col_fpos, 
       details.col_rating, 
       main.col_type,
       main.col_racedesc, 
       main.col_course,
FROM main
     INNER JOIN details on main.col_id = details.col_mainid
WHERE details.col_rating >'165'
  and main.col_type ='h'
ORDER BY CAST (details.col_rating as INT) DESC
```

However I just receive an error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Null' to data type int.
How can I carry Order in numerical order and have the NULL entries ignored when using the col_rating data

Comment: "*A table I have has a column which contains either numbers or a `NULL`*" followed by *"It is a (`VARCHAR(255)`,`Null`)"* Those 2 statements conflict. If it's `varchar` it can (and probably will) contain more than just numbers. If it just holds numbers, then why is it a `varchar` when you have 4 different types of numerical data types to choose from which would be *far* better.

Comment: Also you say that the error you get is *"`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Null' to data type int`"* `'Null'` is a **string**, with the character `N`, `u`, `l` and `l`, not the value `NULL`. `'Null'` contains no numbers, either, which means your opening statement *"which contains either numbers or a `NULL`"* **cannot** be true. A `NULL` and `'Null'` are not the same thing; far from it. Fix your design, fix the problem. Simple

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is your design. It seems like you are storing numerical data in a `varchar` (first wrong thing), and storing the **string** value `'Null'` instead of the value `NULL`. Therefore what you really need to do if fix the design and stop using the string `'Null'` to represent `NULL`. *(`'Null'` and `NULL` are not the same. `NULL` represents an unknown value, and can only be compared to use `IS (NOT) NULL`. `'Null'` is a `varchar` of length 4, and `'Null' = 'Null'` is true. Don't store strings instead of `NULL`; they **do not** behave the same.)*

Firstly you can get rid of the `'Null'` values. Also, we should get rid of any other bad values. We can do this using `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
--Make sure you have a backup ready, just in case!
UPDATE dbo.details
SET col_rating = TRY_CONVERT(int,col_rating);
```

Now we can fix your data type:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.details ALTER COLUMN col_rating int NULL;
```

Now you can run your query without error:

```
sELECT d.col_mainid, 
       d.col_fpos, 
       d.col_rating, 
       m.col_type,
       m.col_racedesc, 
       m.col_course,
FROM main m
     INNER JOIN details d ON m.col_id = d.col_mainid
WHERE d.col_rating > 165
  AND m.col_type ='h'
ORDER BY d.col_rating DESC;
```

Comment: The database and app that loads data into the database was written by a freelancer. The columns/fields are all Varchar ones. The data loaded into the col_rating is either a number or the text Null. There fore it should be treated as a string. I do not think the answer is quite correct. I believe that you should be able to sort a mixed column of numbers and alphabetical letters. Can someone else comment on this...…..Thanks…..Chris

Comment: The freelancer was just all kinds of wrong then, @no9chris . Honestly, someone that creates a database where **every** column is a `varchar` and charging for is is a con-man. That is honestly, terrible work and you are only now just seeing how bad that work is. A string is not a number `'3'` is **greater** than `'100000'`. Numbers and strings are not the same; if you have a column that is for numbers, use a numerical data type. End of story. You ***need*** to fix the mess your contractor has made.

Comment: If you don't believe my expert advice, believe Aaron Bertrand's: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: Okay he may be bad but I am stuck with this in so much as he wrote a .net application which loads the raw data into the database. Given that all that works and the data loads into a website via php scripts okay the only issue is being able to do a search and sort for the col_ratings field. So its working around this freelancers bad habits.

Comment: Also, with your data, @no9chris , `col_rating > '165'` would return rows where `col_rating` has a value of `'Null'`, I *doubt* that is intended either. `NULL` (not `'Null'`) has the **lowest** value.

Comment: You shouldn't be working around the mess, at @no9chris , you ***need*** to fix it. I really mean that; you are in for all kinds of pain if you don't. If that means hiring someone new, who knows what they are doing, then do it. You *really* need it. All your dates, numerical values, etc, etc, they are all wrong, and they could very easily loss meaning. For example, if someone enter the date `'09/08/07'` that could literally be one of 6 dates, and you would have no idea what it would represent; so you would have to effectively remove the data when you clean it.

Comment: BTW this will sort numbers I col_rating by order with NULL at the end of the list (https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/12/06/sorting-numbers-stored-as-string-varchar/) select col_rating from dbo.details
where col_mainid > 43835104
order by replicate ('0',4-len(col_rating)) + col_rating

Comment: But it doesn't fix the problem @no9chris , and it'll only work for the numbers 0-9999.

Comment: I will try changing the col_rating  to an INT and see if it breaks the .NET application.  I am very grateful you have shown how to do this.                     With regard to your last comment the number will never be greater than 199. However while that article provides a way to sort number I would like to hear if anyone has further advise to the problem.

Comment: Hi LARNU  I tried the UPDATE dbo.details
SET col_rating = TRY_CONVERT(int,col_rating); and it did not convert the Null string entries. I then changed the Column to INT  from VARCHAR... (It was a copy/test database) which did change ok. I then ran the .NET application which failed to load....  Any other suggestion for converting Null string to zero number 0?